# Mage.exe fails with "Unrecognized file type" during ClickOnce manual deployment

Tags: .net, clickonce, mage

We run `mage.exe` as part of a NAnt-powered ClickOnce deployment task of our back office desktop application, which contains mostly Windows Forms and a little of WPF.

For one new developer, the following command is failing (some names changed for obfuscation...)

`mage/mage -Update "\\MyServer\Installs\QA\MyClient\Application Files\MyClientUI_4_44_0_1\MyClientUI.exe.manifest" -Name "MyClient QA" -Publisher WeCorp -Version 4.44.0.1 -UseManifestForTrust true`

(Note: the `mage.exe` file is in the relative subpath shown, all by itself in that folder...)

For everyone else on the team, this exact command works fine, but for one of two new developers, if fails with:

`Unrecognized file type - "\\MyServer\Installs\QA\MyClient\Application Files\MyClientUI_4_44_0_1\MyClientUI.exe.manifest"`

Is there some machine-level configuration that affects what `mage.exe` considers to be a "recognized file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we were using a very old version of Mage.exe, and that the up-to-date Windows 10 version did not produce that error message.